# Find, grep and then wc in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to first grep some text in log files created within a DateTime range and then output the count of occurrence of that text.
I have managed to figure out the Unix commands to find the files within a date range and grep for that text in these files. However, I am not able to figure out a way to find the count of occurrence of that text

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "2021-10-06 02:06:00" ! -newermt "2021-10-06 06:30:00" | xargs grep "text"
```

Tried using `xargs wc -l` in the end but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `xargs` in the end if you want to count occurrence, just pipe it to `wc -l`.

[image: screenshot]

```
root@HOST:/var/log/apache2# find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2021-10-06 02:06:00" ! -newermt "2021-10-06 06:30:00"
./error.log
./error.log.1
root@HOST:/var/log/apache2# find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2021-10-06 02:06:00" ! -newermt "2021-10-06 06:30:00" | xargs grep "Apache"
./error.log:[Wed Oct 06 06:25:11.574179 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4138] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1j configured -- resuming normal operations
./error.log.1:[Tue Oct 05 06:25:09.859586 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4138] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1j configured -- resuming normal operations
root@HOST:/var/log/apache2# find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2021-10-06 02:06:00" ! -newermt "2021-10-06 06:30:00" | xargs grep "Apache" | wc -l
2
root@HOST:/var/log/apache2#
```

There's your count of occurence: **2**

Explanation:

- xargs read output of previous commands, then build next command with it
- output of previous command is:

```
./error.log:[Wed Oct 06 06:25:11.574179 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4138] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1j configured -- resuming normal operations
./error.log.1:[Tue Oct 05 06:25:09.859586 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4138] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1j configured -- resuming normal operations
```

- so the result of `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2021-10-06 02:06:00" ! -newermt "2021-10-06 06:30:00" | xargs grep "Apache" | xargs wc -l` is like calling: `wc -l (output of previous command here)`
- but that's not what we want (try calling that manually), what we want is `wc -l < (output of previous command here)`, that is: we pass output of previous command to wc's STDIN
- so, instead of using `xargs`, we should just pipe it

Comment: It worked - Thanks.